# Automatic resizing of LineChart fails if embedded in a pane

Tags: layout, javafx-2

The following program fails to resize the line chart horizontally when embedded in a Pane (or borderpane of anchorpane for the matter)
If the line chart is directly parented to the VBox instead, then everything works as expected.

I found I needed to bind the chart size to the parent pane, which I assume must be done automatically by VBox and HBox.

After trying different combination of enclosing in HBox/VBox, setting growing and alignment policies, I am quite confused about how layouts work.
I observe that there are differences in how ui components behave wrt resizing.

Any clarification (or digest insight on javadoc unclear documentation) is appreciated.

Best regards.

Source edited and clarified

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("X");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y");

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("x = f(y)");

        XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
        data.setName("Serie 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, i * i));
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(data);

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setFillWidth(true);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().add(lineChart);
        hb.setFillHeight(true);
        vb.getChildren().add(hb);

        HBox.setHgrow(lineChart, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(hb, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, the problem of the provided example is solved after modifying this typo:

```
HBox.setHgrow(hb, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

to:

```
HBox.setHgrow(lineChart, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

This fixes resizing horizontally.

When embedded directly in VBox, the chart's size is recomputed on resize, as it is anchored to the VBox, which boundaries change.
When embedded in a HBox, we have to provide a hint for the HBox to grow horizontally, and vertically.
Vertically it's done with:

```
VBox.setVgrow(hb, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Horizontally it's done by requesting its content to occupy all available space, which the fix above is about.